# Parsing empty cells in csv file and storing into mysql

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

I have a csv file which has few cells in some columns empty.Modifying the csv file is not an option as it has around 50k total records.

Whenever I am executing below code it is throwing error as "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'ParentId' at row 1".My database table has null value as yes for column 'ParentID'.But still it is throwing error.How can I edit this code so that it fills in correct values without giving error?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;



public class CSVLoader {


    static int  count;
    private static final 
        //String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) VALUES(${values})";
    String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO ${table} VALUES(${values})";
    private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
    //private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";
    private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";

    private Connection connection;
    private char seprator;

    /**
     * Public constructor to build CSVLoader object with
     * Connection details. The connection is closed on success
     * or failure.
     * @param connection
     */
    public CSVLoader(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        //Set default separator
        this.seprator = ',';
    }

    /**
     * Parse CSV file using OpenCSV library and load in 
     * given database table. 
     * @param csvFile Input CSV file
     * @param tableName Database table name to import data
     * @param truncateBeforeLoad Truncate the table before inserting 
     *          new records.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void loadCSV(String csvFile, String tableName,
            boolean truncateBeforeLoad) throws Exception {

        CSVReader csvReader = null;
        if(null == this.connection) {
            throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
        }
        try {

            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), this.seprator);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

        //String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();
        String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();
        count++;
        if (null == headerRow) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                    "No columns defined in given CSV file." +
                    "Please check the CSV file format.");
        }

        /*String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);
        System.out.println(headerRow.length);
        questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0, questionmarks
                .length() - 1);
        System.out.println(SQL_INSERT);
        String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
        //query = query
            //  .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, ","));
        query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

        System.out.println("Query: " + query);
        */
        //Stirng str1 = "insert into posts values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

        String[] nextLine;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            con = this.connection;
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into posts (Id,PostTypeId,AcceptedAnswerId,ParentId,CreationDate,Score,ViewCount,Body,OwnerUserId,OwnerDisplayName,LastEditorUserId,LastEditorDisplayName,LastEditDate,LastActivityDate,Title,Tags,AnswerCount,CommentCount,FavoriteCount,ClosedDate,CommunityOwnedDate,RowNum) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            if(truncateBeforeLoad) {
                //delete data from table before loading csv
                con.createStatement().execute("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            }

            final int batchSize = 1000;
            int count = 0;
            Date date = null;
            while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

                if (null != nextLine) {
                    int index = 1;
                    for (String string : nextLine) {

                        date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);
                        if (null != date) {
                            ps.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(date
                                    .getTime()));
                        } else {

                            ps.setString(index++, string);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(count);
                    ps.addBatch();
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
                if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                    System.out.println(count);
                    ps.executeBatch();
                }
            }
            ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
            con.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(
                    "Error occured while loading data from file to database."
                            + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (null != ps)
                ps.close();
            if (null != con)
                con.close();

            csvReader.close();
        }
    }

    public char getSeprator() {
        return seprator;
    }

    public void setSeprator(char seprator) {
        this.seprator = seprator;
    }

}
```

Comment: see the line which throws error , mention the line here

Comment: this line is throwing the error "ps.addBatch();"

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case where int column is actually having blank spaces, in such case you can place manual check as below and still go ahead. Hope this answers your doubt.

```
 // check if value is null or blank spaces
    if(certain_value== null || certain.value.trim().length==0){    
      ps.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER); // This will set null value for int type
    }
```